# How are these inputs being recorded and passed to the method?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

This is example code of a simple grade calculation. I don't understand how we are able to take multiple inputs when there isn't a scanner directly in the next line.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        double avg;
        String[] name = new String[10]; //craeting a string array named "name" that has 10
        
        for (int j = 0; j<10; j++)
        {
            System.out.println("What is the name of the student?");
            name[j] = sc.nextLine();    // nextLine because we want the string of the input
            System.out.println("What are their test scores?");
            avg = calculateAverage(j);
            System.out.println("Their average is " + avg + ", that is a " + calculateGrade(avg));
        }
    }
    
    public static double calculateAverage(int j) {
        double [][]gradebook = new double[10][5];
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        double sum = 0;
        for (int v=0; v<5; v++)
        {
            gradebook[j][v] = sc.nextDouble();
            sum = gradebook[j][v] + sum;
        }
        
        double avg = sum / 5;
        return avg;
    }
    
    public static String calculateGrade (double avg)
    {
        if (avg >= 90 && avg <= 100) {
            return "A";
        }
        else if (avg >= 80) {
            return "B";
        }
        else if (avg >= 70) {
            return "C";
        }
        else if (avg >= 60) {
            return "D";
        }
        else {
            return "F";
        }
    }
}
```

I know that there's a scanner in calculateAverage, but what makes it possible for a user to respond with multiple numbers and those inputs being pushed into calculateAverage? Shouldn't there be a scanner in main that directly records the inputs? Are the inputs somehow being directly pushed into calculateAverage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scanner in calculate average reads in numbers from `gradebook[j][v] = sc.nextDouble();`
whenever this line is reached the code will stop and wait for input.
After input, the loop continues and asks for another number as input.

Comment: Ah okay I see it now, it makes sene. Thank you for pointing that out! I couldn't get my head around it for some reason.